# How to map a set of colors to a string sequence and plot it in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a list of strings (for example, actual string is 5000 characters) :

```
sequence='NGHHENIMHNYRBIFIFEMRHHCFFFJUUSVUUUUNXMTUSRHXOMEJNGKVUUUUVUUUVTUUVUWWSVULVUUUUUUUUUUUUWXQJUQRTXQRHM'
```

the sequence contains alphabets  `'A'` to `'Y'`. 
I want to map colors to each of the alphabets and plot like the diagram below.

expected output (this is a example output) :

[image]

I have tried the following :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


colors=sns.color_palette("coolwarm", 25)
string=[]
for char in sequence:
   string.append(char)


df=pd.DataFrame({'col':string}, index=range(len(string)))
letter2num = dict(zip(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"), np.arange(25)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array( [letter2num[i] for i in df.values.flat] ).reshape(df.shape))
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,19))
ax.imshow(df2.values, vmin=0, vmax=len(cmap.colors), cmap=cmap)
```

However, this gives a verticle and thin straight line. Can somebody put in the right direction?

my output :

[image]

Comment: works fine on my system. what's your output? what do you expect?

Comment: Just a row in the above image( e.g  row in front of 54). Can you show your output in anyway?

Comment: @QuangHoang My out is attached in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `pcolormesh`

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style('white')
colors=sns.color_palette("coolwarm", 25)

df=pd.DataFrame({'col':sequence}, index=range(len(sequence)))
letter2num = dict(zip(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"), np.arange(25)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array( [letter2num[i] for i in df.values.flat] ).reshape(df.shape))
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,10))
plt.pcolormesh(df2.values, vmin=0, vmax=len(cmap.colors), cmap=cmap)
plt.xticks([])
cbar=plt.colorbar( fraction=0.46,ticks=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],pad=0.3)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['A', 'B', 'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y'],size=15,verticalalignment='bottom',horizontalalignment='left' )
cbar.ax.tick_params(size=0, pad=5.4)
yticks=['0','50','100','150','200']
plt.yticks([0,1250,2500,3750,5000],yticks,size=15)
plt.ylabel('Time(ns)',Size=20)
```

[image]